# line-height img alt tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the line-height of an image src-attribute but am failing. It seems the line-height can't be controlled with css?

```
img {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
    line-height:10px;
}
```

Please have a look at this example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nerdess/qvLw2/2/

Comment: Could your issue be better solved by using a top margin?

Comment: line-height for image? You can't do that.

Comment: why your sentences are placed on img tag?

Comment: what exactly do u want........@nerdess

Comment: they are no sentences, the src-tag contains a description of the image for accessibility. the src-tag is visible if the image is not loaded and all i want to do is style it a bit

Comment: ps: no idea why this post gets voted down as the question is totally legit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line-height doesn't effect images you can look for a different workaround read this:
http://api.jquery.com/error/ - using jquery

Comment: Great, please approve the solution